# Difference between survfit and survreg in r

Tags: r, survival

What is the difference between [survreg](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/survreg.html) and [survfit](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/2.11-4/topics/survfit)?

> Survreg:
> Fit a parametric survival regression model. These are
> location-scale models for an arbitrary transform of the time variable;
> the most common cases use a log transformation, leading to accelerated
> failure time models.

> Survfit: Computes an estimate of a survival curve for censored data
> using either the Kaplan-Meier or the Fleming-Harrington method or
> computes the predicted survivor function for a Cox proportional
> hazards model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In survival analysis, why do we use semi-parametric models (Cox proportional hazards) instead of fully parametric models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64739/in-survival-analysis-why-do-we-use-semi-parametric-models-cox-proportional-haz). It's just the difference between a parametric (`survreg`) and a non- or semi-parametric model (`survfit`).

Comment: yes, thanks! why is there so much more content available about survfit than about survreg on google?

Comment: The non-parametric Kaplan-Meier or semi-parametric Cox models handled by `survfit` don't require knowledge of the underlying baseline survival curve. Cox models do require a proportional hazards (PH) assumption, but that can be checked from the data and the model can often then be adapted to fit PH. In particular, a Weibull model is a PH model but not all PH models are Weibull models. So a Cox model with results displayed by `survfit` is very often the initial go-to choice, particularly in clinical survival work. The better distinction should be `survreg` versus `coxph`, the model fitters.